# Identify a particular row in dynamic partial view using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view which is not strongly typed. it is dynamic:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Student.Models" %>

<div>
<table id="TA">
        <tr>
            <th>Teaching Assistant</th>
            <th>Course ID</th>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Delete Row</th>
        </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div>
<table id="StudentAction">
    <tr>
       <td><select name="TeachingAssistant"></select> </td>
       <td><select name="CourseID"></select></td>
       <td><select name="Day"></select></td>
       <td><input name="delete" type="image" src="/delete.png"  onclick="javascript:delete('this')"/></td>
   </tr>

</table>
</div>
```

Now I add a new row using JQuery every time a new value is selected from "TeachingAssistant" select list.

Also, there is a delete image which on click should delete that particular row. How can I identify a particular row based on the delete image clicked? For e.g if the delete image for row third is clicked then how can I identify third row and send that to JQuery? For e.g. I want to identify the row on which the delete image was clicked and send it to delete function in JQuery below, using "this" does not work, is there any other way to doing this? again this is not a strongly typed view, its dynamic.

```
function delete(val) {

    $(this).parent().remove();

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you wired up the delete method with click event of the button? When you said "this" does not work, what error are you getting? Can you please post your complete code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some class to trigger the event.

```
<td><input name="delete" type="image" src="/delete.png" class="delete"/></td>
```

Then use `closest` to get its row.

```
$('#StudentAction').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/VRYWT/)

or for old versions:

```
$('#StudentAction .delete').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: I get the following error when trying it your way: 
"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method". 
On line: "$('#StudentAction').on('click', '.delete', function() {"

Comment: @user793468 Are you sure it's the same code ? Look my demo, it works.

Comment: Yes, its exactly the same. seems to be version issue

Answer (score 0):

If the deleteThis function is defined in the same html page with your table. Then following should work.

```
/* This will send the table row to deleteThis function */
<td>
    <input type =".." onclick="javascript:deleteRow($(this).parent().parent())"/>
</td>
```

`$(this)` refers to `input` element, parent of this input element gives you `td` and parent of td gives you the `tr`.

```
function deleteRow(val) {
    $(val).remove();

}
```

If your deleteThis function is defined in external .js file, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108139/javascript-linking-onclick-to-a-js-to-a-file).

Since you want to pass the tr element to function, I proposed this solution. However, `$(this).parent().parent()` looks quite ugly. I would suggest using Ricardo Lohmann's solution.